# webservice authentication - do I need SSL?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, jboss7.x

I have a question about whether I really need SSL or not. The scenario is as follows:

I have two applications at the moment, they are both Java webapps. One of them is getting data from another via RESTful web service secured by Spring Security, but my problem is that it sends username and password in URL so the other app can authenticate and authorize it using LDAP. In the end both apps will be running on JBoss AS 7 server so even though one of them is a client and the other one is server they will be running on one server and that confuses me a little bit (even if they will use multiple instances of JBoss they will still be both in the same network). Also signing certificate by third party seems unnecessary here because I don't really care if anyone will trust my server app and again I found that I can implement my own Certificate Authority but it really seems to me as an overkill.

So to summarize it: if I only care about request (or just its parts - username and password) being encrypted do I need to enable SSL and provide all it needs or is there any easier way to achieve it?

Comment: is this server publicly accessible?

Comment: No. It's an internal network.

Comment: I think answer depends on , Whether the end point exposed to outside network. Assume the url is allowed in your network firewall, it is vulnerable irrespective of where actual client resides on.

Comment: I think that answers your question - if you aren't worried about protecting the communication between two internal components, then yes SSL is overkill

Comment: Sure, but I'm just thinking if there is any other way of encrypting requests parameters without need to setting up keystore and certificates

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/encrypting-and-obscuring-data-between-site-user-without-ssl This might Help